# Color management between Mac and PC

Tags: color-management

I have seen posts for color management between computer and printer, but I'm having a hard time finding the answer to color management between a mac and the printer and a pc and the printer.

I work in a small office – in my role, I use a mac while the rest of the company uses a PC. The problem occurs when pc users print certain color documents (e.g. our letterhead) on our color printer (HP CP 4025 – yes, it's old!), the colors are off.

Our logo is a shade of purple, but it will print out blue. How do I determine the correct colors to use to create the letterhead so it prints correctly from the PC?

When I print from my Mac, it's correct. The error occurs when the PC users print a Word document or PDF.

Comment: Hi bdmnn, Welcome to Graphic Design Stackexchange. Colour management is effective when all components of the network are under the control of the colour management system. Are the PCs using any system of colour management? Are the Macs?

Comment: What programs are they using on the PC side? The more sophisticated graphics/layout programs under Windows may be able to do color management, but not Office or similar programs.

Answer (score 0):

Before printing check this:

- Mac Monitor Calibration is well done
- PC Monitor calibration is well done
- The documents profile are the same as the color printer profile

Having all this, there won't be any problem (or at least not so big) matching colors when printing from any computer.

Comment: - Calibrate the printer as well.